# How to determine what is low-quality or non-unique content for getting approved with Google Adsense?

Tags: google-adsense, duplicate-content, content

I just received a Google Adsense rejection for a site which I can't share for work purposes. Here is the image of the notice.

[image]

Here are the links that are in that rejection notice:

- Minimum content requirements: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9335564#minimum_content_requirements
- Make sure your site has unique high quality content and a good user experience: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10015918
- Webmaster quality guidelines for thin content: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175#thin-content
- Webmaster quality guidelines: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1348737
- Sites without content or with low value content: https://support.google.com/publisherpolicies/answer/11036238

Two parts to this question:

1. How do I determine what is the low-quality or non-unique content they are talking about? Is there some human I can get in touch with at Google to help guide me through understanding better what I need to change/do to get approved?
2. Without human communication, how can I determine what is low-quality or non-unique content?

For context, let's take a color website, like these:

- [color-hex.com](https://www.color-hex.com/color/767171)
- [colorhexa.com](https://www.colorhexa.com/767171)

There are at least 10 websites I have seen on colors alone, each with Google Adsense integration. That to me means "non-unique content", but then why are they approved?

That begs the question, can you really not have duplicate / non-unique content? For color websites it is obvious, they each show a page per color. Why is this not rejected?

For other sites, is it really truly UNIQUE content? Take news websites for example, left wing or right wing news. There are probably 100 left wing news sites, which all share roughly the same news stories (albeit they are written/described by different authors). The *topic* of the articles is the same, they are basically duplicate websites. But the *content* of the articles is technically different because they are different prose by different authors. To me that is duplicate content, but maybe to Google that is unique content?

Take dictionaries for another case, there are dozens of online dictionaries, each with pretty much the exact same underlying content/data, just rendered with different prose by different authors (Oxford dictionary, Cambridge dictionary, dictionary.com, etc.). They all have Google Adsense for the most part, why are they not flagged for duplicate content?

Without knowing more about my specific case, how can I figure out what content is low quality or not unique, and fix it? How do I know when I've reached a state where I know my website will be approved by Google Adsense?